# MYSQL PHP triggered by Android (Corona sdk) makes trouble about row/column

Tags: php, android, mysql, variables, coronasdk

This is my simple "give-android-my-data-script":

```
$email = $_POST["email"];
$column = $_POST["column"];
$data = $_POST["data"];
mysql_query( "UPDATE members SET '$column' = '$data' WHERE email = '$email'") or die( "database query failed!" );
echo "data retrieved" . $email . $column . $data;
```

Everything is working fine **IF** but if I change `'$column'` for example into `active` (which is a row)

**Echo tells me all 3 variables are there, but "database query failed!", too**

So I'm sitting here - without a clue - 02:22am in germany...

Maybe someone can help me find the mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the data inside `$_POST["column"]` has a matching column name in your members table.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE members SET `".$column."` = '".$data."' WHERE email = '".$email."'")
```

Your query is also very prone to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). You should be using `MySQLi_*`  instead.

Comment: thanks, forgot that " and ' stuff. Should go to sleep. And thanks for the hint with injection. I'll use pdo! :)